# Additional zero byte in RFC 5915 ECDSA public key generated by OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, cryptography, asn.1

I'm trying to understand the format in which OpenSSL stores private ECDSA keys. Supposedly it is in [RFC 5915](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5915.html) ECPrivateKey format (which apparently was first defined by [SECG, see C.4](https://www.secg.org/SEC1-Ver-1.0.pdf)):

```
ECPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
  version        INTEGER { ecPrivkeyVer1(1) } (ecPrivkeyVer1),
  privateKey     OCTET STRING,
  parameters [0] ECParameters {{ NamedCurve }} OPTIONAL,
  publicKey  [1] BIT STRING OPTIONAL
}
```

Which fits very well:
[image: Online ASN.1 JavaScript decoder screenshot with 66 byte publicKey bit string highlighted] ([Also online here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MHcCAQEEIJmBX3aXvprsnhd7SPOETKLnYQRH2S9ZLH7nEbGysQXroAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAEHODZEGxGLpS6MxFEJFswFT4K7gGONCuXceu-eyLj4r0xqjLGWsTG18H5Jj1RfTlE8UTdI8F84bmZeugASAaTGA).)

What does not fit is the highlighted *publicKey* data structure. It contains 66 bytes **with a leading 0x00 byte**. According to the standard "publicKey contains the elliptic curve public key associated with the private key in question.  The format of the public key is specified in Section 2.2 of [RFC5480]" which says:

```
    The first octet of the OCTET STRING indicates whether the key is
    compressed or uncompressed.  The uncompressed form is indicated
    by 0x04 and the compressed form is indicated by either 0x02 or
    0x03 (see 2.3.3 in [SEC1]).  The public key MUST be rejected if
    any other value is included in the first octet.
```

**Thus the leading 0x00 is explicitly forbidden**. The rest of the field fits perfectly again: 0x04 indicates uncompressed and NIST P-256 ("prime256v1") uses a 256bit Galois field, so a curve point can be expressed in two 32byte coordinates and thus fills the remaining 64bytes. So one leading zero byte, one no-compression-used byte and two 32 byte coordinates make up the 66 byte ASN.1 BIT STRING payload.

**The question is: Why is the leading zero byte present?**

---

The private key file content for reference:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIJmBX3aXvprsnhd7SPOETKLnYQRH2S9ZLH7nEbGysQXroAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEHODZEGxGLpS6MxFEJFswFT4K7gGONCuXceu+eyLj4r0xqjLGWsTG
18H5Jj1RfTlE8UTdI8F84bmZeugASAaTGA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: If the length of the bit string is not a multiple of 8, it is padded with 0 values at the end until this condition is met. The number of unused bits is prepended to the bit string. In the current example the bit string is 0x041C...18, so it has a length of 65 bytes, must not be padded, and thus 0x00 is prepended (which is the value in question here). For completness: 0x03 and 0x42 are simply the identifier for a bit string and the length of the bit string 0x00041C...18, respectively. S. e.g. [here](https://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html), *5.4 Bit String*.

Comment: Thx @Topaco, So this zero byte isn't actually part of the payload. The presentations of all three parsers that I used had highly suggestive spacing / coloring, but I could have questioned where the exact number of bits would go... Why does the standard use a BIT STRING type here, though? The data is clearly defined as bytes. Something to do with conventions previously established with RSA moduli?

Comment: Although your key is a SEC1 key, presumably [this reasoning](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6843/how-do-i-unpack-the-x-and-y-values-from-the-bitstring-in-a-der-ecdsa-public-key#comment13670_6843) applies here as well.